# quaternion for a line joining two points

Tags: python, 3d, gis, quaternions, gltf

how can I find the quaternion rotation of a line joining two points (u and v) in the 3d space?

I read many answers online but they all seem to have a second vector for finding the quaternion rotation but I seem to only have a single vector (which is `v - u`).

I am trying to draw a line in a gltf model using pygltflib.

Comment: In glTF, you don't need a quaternion to draw a line.  There are ways to connect glTF vertices with line(s), is that what you're looking for?  A quaternion is needed for "rotation" of a glTF node, but that doesn't get you a line.  Can you edit your question and add more details?

Comment: hey @emackey, 
I am trying to add a line (or a cylinder) node and rotate it (to make it look like a bond between two atom nodes). How else can do it?
I need to be able to do this on the fly